# Is there a plugin to generate emmet styled html for jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, emmet

Let's say i want to create html elements using jquery. And to that i have to type `$('<div>')...` But then i have to append other stuff to it and so on. I could write whole html in one go which is fine but it'd be cleaner if i could do something like this: `$('body').append($.emmet('p>lipsum+ul.list>li{items}*5');`

I think this would be powerful thing to have. And should be very possible. It'd be good if such thing exists also for express and works with jade.

Main reason i guess i want this is so my javascript code doesn't get all crowded due to stuff like `$('body'),append('<div class='sdfd' data-dbndbd='dsd'><p class= '33'> ....")`

Comment: this could be a new idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at jquery-zencoding plugin https://github.com/zodoz/jquery-ZenCoding

It also has primitive data-binding possibilities.

Comment: i think it works exactly as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the jquery.emmet... https://github.com/Krizz/jquery.emmet

**Addendum**: After a more careful review, looks like the jquery.emmet project is dead or stalled. Good news is that the HTML.js may be exactly what you need. Take a look at: http://nbubna.github.io/HTML/

Comment: hi, how am i suppose to use it, any tuts or docs anywhere

Comment: Hello Muhammad,
I was looking more carefully and that first link seems to be obsolete. However, I found something that may be exactly what you need. Check it out: http://nbubna.github.io/HTML/
I will update the answer...

Comment: Hi, Julio How has it been

Comment: Let me know if the HTML.js is what you need. ;)

Comment: can you give some example of how would i get html out of this string **p.d+ul>li{sdf}*5**.

Comment: Based on their manual, you can use: **HTML.body.add('p.d+ul>li{sdf}*5');**
Also in the manual says: " __The standard HTML.js artifact comes with the "emmet" extension, which lets you use emmet abbreviations to add elements to the DOM. This extension supports most emmet features, except grouping and numbering. Those may be added later. __ ". Here you can find all you need about emmet and what is supported by HTML.js: [link](http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax).

Comment: this will insert html into dom, i want only html